# how to fetch/import from github to visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2013

Suppose that i have a web application solution on GitHub.
How do i fetch or import the whole web application solution from github to visual studio 2013?

I am expecting something like this:
File -> Open -> Open from source -> enter githublink and credentials -> auto create project and fetch from github

but seems like i cannot found the solution

P/S: I am not looking forward on solution that download the entire zip file from github, open in visual studio and recommit it into github.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Connect Visual Studio 2012 with git (github)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19892232/how-to-connect-visual-studio-2012-with-git-github)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open the Team Explorer tab, at the bottom of the Connect page (power plug icon) you'll see a list of Git Repositories, enter the https uri to your github project and hit clone.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19893242/736079