# How to connect to git repo in VisualStudio 2012?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012

I have an empty github repo. I downloaded Sourcetree and connected to the repo, now I wanted to use it in Visual Studio 2012, all the tutorials are showing to do it in the Team Explorer Tab, but mine looks like this: [image]

without any option to connect local repo.. :(

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19892232/how-to-connect-visual-studio-2012-with-git-github

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Connect Visual Studio 2012 with git (github)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19892232/how-to-connect-visual-studio-2012-with-git-github)